# Is it possible to run an arbitrary application from a keyboard shortcut with VS Code?

Tags: command-line, visual-studio-code, exe

I would like to configure a keyboard shortcut to execute a command line instruction inside Visual Studio Code. As it happens, I would like this instruction to open an application, preferably with the filename of the currently viewed file passed as a parameter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer is to create a new task and bind it to a key combination:

http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks